# How to build, compile and run a Scala project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to evaluate a Scala project that I have found on Github, namely [TRank](https://github.com/MEM0R1ES/TRank).

I found the build file `build.sbt`. I managed to install Scala and sbt via homebrew and then run the command `sbt run` on the project root folder. Doing so ended up with an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Now the project files are in the `src/main/scala/io/mem0r1es/trank` and when I try to compile via `scalac` or run `sbt run` there I get a bunch of errors about objects not being members of the base packaged i.e. `object ranking is not a member of package io.mem0r1es.trank`

I would greatly appreciate some help knowing how to run this Scala project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've already noticed the project is managed by sbt.

In order to package a project, i.e. creating a jar with all the project artifacts that are supposed to be distributed, you execute `package`.

```
> package
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/TRank/}trank...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 13 Scala sources to /Users/jacek/sandbox/TRank/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/TRank/target/scala-2.10/trank_2.10-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
```

By default sbt manages sources under `src/main/scala` directory. That's where you could find an `App` object to run.

In sbt, `run` searches all the sources under `src/main/scala` for applications.

```
> help run
Runs a main class, passing along arguments provided on the command line.
```

If a project has no main classes, the error is printed out:

```
> run
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 24, 2014 9:40:52 PM
```

It does mean that the project has no main classes, but there are other ways to "prove" that an API works properly - using tests.

Execute `test` to fire the tests:

```
> test
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /Users/jacek/sandbox/TRank/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[warn] there were 2 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] ANC_DEPTHSpec:
[info] An ANC_DEPTH ranker
[info] - should rank types properly
[info] - should not fail when no types are provided
[info] ANCESTORSSpec:
[info] An ANCESTORS ranker
[info] - should rank types properly
[info] - should not fail when no types are provided
[info] DEPTHSpec:
[info] A DEPTH ranker
[info] - should rank types by maximum depth
[info] - should not fail when no types are provided
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... [info] PreProcessorSpec:
[info] A PreProcessor
[info] - should remove boilerplate from HTML content
[info] - should leave intact textual content
[info] - should not fail with empty content
done [2.8 sec].
[info] NERSpec:
[info] A NER
[info] - should extract entity labels
[info] - should not fail with content without Named Entities
[info] - should not fail with empty content
[info] Passed: Total 12, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 12
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 24, 2014 9:42:09 PM
```

So, to learn the project you should review the sources of the tests (under `src/test/scala`) and a scaladoc that you can generate using `doc` task:

```
> doc
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/jacek/sandbox/TRank/target/scala-2.10/api...
model contains 20 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 24, 2014 9:43:22 PM
```

You could also use `console` task to enter Scala REPL and play with the types yourself.

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

With the tests, the scaladoc and the Scala REPL, you should be all set to learn the API of the project.

Comment: looking at the Readme in the main repo they say " it is enough to create a TRanker object with any textual content" `class TRanker(content: String)` does that mean that i can do that directly in REPL ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it won't get "persisted" in your source files. Scala REPL is fine for prototyping, but once you close the REPL session the changes are gone - you could find `:save` quite useful also.

Comment: thanks for your replies @Jacek. I dropped integrating that API previously as i spent so much trying to get the hang of it. But i will be needing that very soon, i was wondering if you have some time the following days to have a chat about running this piece of code locally and as an API called from external application (Node.js for example)

Answer (score 2):

TRank is a SBT project. You need to install SBT from this site http://www.scala-sbt.org/

Then you can build it like so:

```
sbt clean compile package
```

This will create a jar file for you in target/ folder. Once you get the jar file, you can use it just like you use Java Jar files ( except that you must use scala to include scala library jars automatically ):

```
scala -cp /path/to/trank_2.10-1.0.jar com.example.SomeMainClass
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have managed to see the .jar file but when i try to run it i get `no main manifest attribute, in trank_2.10-1.0.jar` do you know what this can be?

Comment: That is the project configuration. You may want to go through the project details and find out classes with `main` method, and then run it like so `scala -cp /path/to/trank_2.10-1.0.jar com.example.SomeMainClass`

Comment: I updated my answer. If you are using `java -jar` you also need to include Scala library jar files. Otherwise simply use `scala` instead of `java`.

Comment: thanks for your help along the way. Apprently there is no main method in the .scala files. The project is supposed to act as an API so i dont know if this can be reason. If so, how would i be able to access this API ? i have linked the project Github in case you want to have a quick look (which i would greatly appreciate)