# error while building apache spark

Tags: maven-2, sbt, apache-spark

i get the following error while building apache spark on open suse. any pointers?

```
test:/siva/spark-1.1.0 # sbt/sbt assembly
[info] Loading project definition from /siva/spark-1.1.0/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /root/.sbt/0.13/staging/ec3aa8f39111944cc5f2/sbt-pom-reader/project
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[info] Loading project definition from /siva/spark-1.1.0/project
org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.spark:spark-parent:1.1.0
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:14 from/to central ( http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo.maven.apache.org from  http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/14/apache-14.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 11

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException(DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:841)
....
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.spark:spark-parent:1.1.0
[error] [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:pom:14 from/to central ( http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo.maven.apache.org from  http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/14/apache-14.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 11
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: backward-delete-word
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: backward-delete-word
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: down-history
[INFO] Unable to bind key for unsupported operation: up-history

Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

building the spark did not throw such error in ubuntu and redhat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build, compile and run a Scala project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018151/how-to-build-compile-and-run-a-scala-project)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  The link you provided did not refer in any way to Suse.

Comment: It didn't, but refer to the official way to build Spark. It should be `mvn` not `sbt`.

Comment: but then, how could i build it in ubuntu and redhat without errors using sbt?

Comment: You shouldn't expect building Spark using sbt as it's no longer the official way. It may or may not work (and honestly is a waste of your time).